# What does this mean 什么时候我也会看到你们受这份罪的，你们两个?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand this sentence:

> [image: 什么时候我也会看到你们受这份罪的，你们两个。]
>
> 什么时候我也会看到你们受这份罪的，你们两个。
> I'll be seeing you some time, you two.
> <sub>(玛帝尔达 (Matilda), page 127; [English version](http://jssisdubai.com/document/uploaded/matilda.pdf) pdf page 111)</sub>

It doesn't seem too well matched to the English text:

> When [什么时候] I [我] also [也] will [会] see [看到] you (plural) [你们] ??? [受这份罪的]，you both [你们两个].

Perhaps 什么时候我也 combines to mean something like "I always...".

**Question**: What does this sentence mean?

Comment: It's matilda, I have learned several years ago. If you can give the whole story image, may I will translate better. Oh, pool English

Comment: I can't see the image; I think Imgur is blocked here.  So hopefully it looks okay.

Comment: I'ts a bad translation of "I'll be seeing you (suffer) some time, you two"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[什么时候] - Some day

[我也会] - I too will

[看到] - see

[你们受] - you suffer

[这份罪的]- this pain/ suffering

罪 in 受罪 doesn't mean "crime". It is referring to "pain/ suffering" and 受罪(suffer - *like being punished*) is a synonym of 受苦 (suffer- *pain*)

[你们两个] - the two of you (*The speaker add this as a declaimer to make sure his target take notice how serious he is*)

> "什么时候我也会看到你们受这份罪的,你们两个!"
>
> "Some day, I will see you suffer this pain too, the two of you"

Similar example: "You will pay for this! All of you will pay!" (你們會為此付出代價! 你們所有人都會付出代價!)

Answer (score 2):

“You two… Someday I will see you both suffering from this.”

Possible syntax error exists. Please let me know :)

#### UPDATE

Sorry for the misinterpretation above: that is not an answer to the question in OP.

According to the English version, the Chinese translation contained something that may not even exist in the original transcript.

> 什么时候我也会看到你们受这份罪的, 你们两个.

This seems to be a curse if no more context involved, whose corresponding translation is presented above. But according to the book, it seems that this Hortensia simply means "I'll be seeing you [be treated like this] some time, you two". This is actually a simple warning that the Headmistress would be very harsh on these little girls, and Hortensia seems to be in audience only, i.e. stand by and watch the scene.

Of course, a treatment described in that tale is truly something that one might "suffer" [since this is not only something one might going through, but also with so much agony and pain], so the Chinese translator used “受这份罪”. Instead I would say

> 有一天/我/也会看到/你们两个[被这么对待的吧].
>
> Some time / I /will be seeing / you two [be treated like this].

Comment: No syntax error, excellent translation!

Answer (score 1):

(when you suffered from trouble ,may someone laugh at you then you say this ) you two will get in trouble like me, oneday. (it seems like speaker is angry and ask you don't laugh at him. )
im a chinese, you can ask if you want .but my English is pooooool